# Java - replace compoment in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am struggling with java GUI - thanks for any help in advance! I have a JFrame in which I have several components: **button (Jbutton)** that triggers action listener, **comp** which is a component Im trying to replace a **JScrollPane** with a component in it (it doesnt matter what type of component, could be text field, table or anything).

I would like to trigger an action - delete the component, place a new one on the same place as the deleted one and repaint the window (I am using this to show different types of text fields and JTables). This is what I have:

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(comp);
this.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//this works so far - first time I display this is ok!

private void replace() {
 comp = new Component(...); //name and type of the components is not important
 sp = new JSCrollPane(comp);
 this.remove(sp); //remove old component
 add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 repaint();
 revalidate();
}
```

Why doesnt function replace work? It doesnt do anything (it changes the component in logic so if I access the content of comp, it is refreshed but it still shows the old one).

I wrote it kinda symbolic, cause my code is very long... Thanks for any help!
edit: forgot one line in my code..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not necessary for you to try to remove the scroll pane as you did.

To change the component shown by the scroll pane simply make this call:

```
sp.setViewportView(new Component(...));
```

after that call, the old component is removed from view and replaced by the new component.

So your code should look somewhat like this:

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(comp);
this.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

private void replace() {
    comp = new Component(...); //name and type of the components is not important
    sp.setViewportView(comp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the look of your code, the first scrollpane you added (this.add) is different to the one you removed (this.remove). Test the boolean returned from remove to see if it was actually removed. I think you'll find it isn't.

Comment: This was the mistake, I should have removed sp first and then create it and add it again...

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution in [this board](http://www.coderanch.com/t/340488/GUI/java/Adding-removing-components-JPanel) :

```
jpanel.remove(component); //remove component from your jpanel in this case i used jpanel 
jpanel.revalidate(); 
jframe.repaint();//repaint a JFrame jframe in this case 

to add: 
jpanel.add(component); //add component to jpanel in this case i used jpanel 
jpanel.revalidate(); 
jframe.repaint();//repaint a JFrame jframe in this case
```

See if this works for you. Haven't tried it myself...